# I try to implement an OAuth protocol in order to allow the users to login in via GitHub in my Project but after login in the

Tags: symfony, github, oauth-2.0

The connection for this site is not secure 127.0.0.1 sent an invalid response.
Try running network diagnostics with Get Help.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

I try to implement an OAuth 2.0 protocol  in order to allow the users to login in via GitHub  in my Project but after login in the call-back page return me this exception

Answer (score 0):

to fix this error you have to secure the version of your application in running this command in your shell
"Composer server:ca:install"
for more details [Enabling TLS](https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup/symfony_server.html)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).